# How to loop this correctly?

Tags: java

I want to loop the prompt every time a user will enter the fruit. However, `Fruit 0` always prints. I can't understand how this loop works.

```java
int i = 0;
do
{
    System.out.print("Fruit " + i + ": ");
    String inF = scan.nextLine();
    i++;
}
while(i<=numF);
```

I expect the output to be like this:

```
Fruit 1: (input)
Fruit 2: (input)
Fruit 3: (input)
Fruit 4: (input)
```

However, the program output is this:

```
Fruit 0: Fruit 1: (input)
Fruit 2: (input)
Fruit 3: (input)
Fruit 4: (input)
```

Comment: Start from 1 (`int i = 1`) or move the `i++` before the `print`

Comment: Improved code and output formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You declare and initialize `i` with `0`, and you increment it *after* you display your message. Two possible fixes.

One, start at one to being with like

```
int i = 1;
```

**or**; Two, increment before you display the message. Like,

```
i++;
System.out.print("Fruit " + i + ": ");
String inF = scan.nextLine();
// i++;
```

**or**; Two and a half, increment when you display your message (and use formatted io). Like,

```
System.out.printf("Fruit %d: ", i++);
String inF = scan.nextLine();
```

**or**; just use a `for`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numF; i++) {
    System.out.printf("Fruit %d: ", i + 1);
    String inF = scan.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: The output shows like this... Fruit 1: Fruit 2: (input) Fruit 3: (input) Fruit 4: (input)

Comment: I can't type any input at Fruit 1

Comment: Your fourth suggestion works but there's no prompt for input at Fruit 1. Only Fruit 2 to 4 has the prompt. I wanted to input also at Fruit 1.

Comment: Since you don't print a new line, you should flush() after every print. Otherwise, posted examples should all behave identically.

Answer (score 0):

It should be as:-

```
int i = 0;
do
{

    i++;
    System.out.print("Fruit " + i + ": ");
    String inF = scan.nextLine();

}
while(i<=numF);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the loop starts with 0, the first output will be 0.

```
    int i = 0;
    do // i has value 0 here
    {
        System.out.print("Fruit " + i + ": "); // First iteration, i still has value 0 here
        String inF = scan.nextLine();
        i++;
    }
    while(i<=numF); // This will repeat until i<=numF, depending on your value for numF
```

Example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        int numF = 4;
        int i = 0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        do // i has value 0 here
        {
            System.out.print("Fruit " + i + ": "); // First iteration, i still has value 0 here
            String inF = scan.nextLine();
            i++;
        }
        while (i <= numF);
    }
}
```

Output from the above:

```
Hello World!
Fruit 0: 1
Fruit 1: 2
Fruit 2: 3
Fruit 3: 4
Fruit 4: 5

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Your code works however, i wanted to start in Fruit 1

Comment: And I've been encountering this since my previous code, there's no prompt for user input on the first fruit.